# Which method is used to start a new asynchronous request/response cycle?

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

This question is in a book I have:

> Which method is used to start a new asynchronous request/response cycle?

The possible answers to this questions are

```
A. ServletContext.newAsync()
B. ServletContext.startAsync()
C. ServletRequest.newAsync()
D. ServletRequest.runASync()
E. ServletRequest.getAsyncContext()
```

And the correct answer regards to the book is C, but I can't find that method in the API.

The explanation of the book is that the method returns an `AsyncContext` but is executed on `ServletRequest` (not `ServletContext`).

Is it possible that the answer is `ServletRequest.startAsync()` and the book has it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It does look like the book is wrong.

The correct way to do it is with `ServletRequest.startAsync()`, 
this method puts the request in async mode, initializes and returns the `AsyncContext`.

`ServletRequest` doesn't even have a method called `newAsync`

Seems non of those answers are correct

Comment: B neither, because it uses ServletContext instead of ServletRequest. There is no correct answer I think :s
I think you are right, `ServletRequest.startAsync()` would be the correct answer.